# Google AdSense ads in Angular 2 components?

Tags: angular, adsense

I'm trying to load some Responsive ads in an `AdComponent` in my app. The component is dead simple:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FORM_DIRECTIVES, CORE_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'ad',
  templateUrl: 'app/views/ad.html',
  directives: [ FORM_DIRECTIVES, CORE_DIRECTIVES ]
})
export class AdComponent {}
```

`ad.html`:

```
<div class="demo-card-wide mdl-card mdl-shadow--2dp ad-card">
  <div class="mdl-card__supporting-text">
    <script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
    <ins class="adsbygoogle"
        style="display:block"
        data-ad-client="ca-pub-0123456789"
        data-ad-slot="0123456789"
        data-ad-format="rectangle, horizontal"></ins>
    <script>
    (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
    </script>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm finding that these script tags don't make it into the UI and [this seems to be a purposeful decision](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4903).

I might be able to move around some of the code such as the js reference into the head of my index.html and the `window.adsbygoogle` part into the component constructor but I'm not sure if these kinds of modifications are allowed or if there's a better alternative to get these ads to work in Angular 2.

Does anybody have any experience with Google's Adsense ads working in Angular 2? Is there a different, proper way to do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's what I've come up with and have working. I admit it may be stretching the "don't modify our code" rule of adsense, but I am doing my best to keep the heart of the code doing the same thing it's supposed to be doing:

```
// ad component
import { Component, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FORM_DIRECTIVES, CORE_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'ad',
  templateUrl: 'app/views/ad.html',
  directives: [ FORM_DIRECTIVES, CORE_DIRECTIVES ]
})
export class AdComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    try {
      (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
    } catch (e) {}
  }
}

// ad.html
<div class="demo-card-wide mdl-card mdl-shadow--2dp ad-card">
  <div class="mdl-card__supporting-text">
    <ins class="adsbygoogle" style="display:inline-block;width:330px;height:120px" data-ad-client="my_client_number" data-ad-slot="my_ad_slot_number"></ins>
  </div>
</div>
```

The design of my website has ads in Material Design Lite cards so that's the 2 outer divs in the view. The `<ins>` tag is cut and paste exactly the same tag adsense gave me.

I used `AfterViewInit` because it seems that adsense watches the array `adsbygoogle` to know when to scan for a new ad in the DOM. You don't want to modify this array until the DOM has the `<ins>` tag.

I wrapped the line in a try/catch because testing with an ad blocker showed that the component would throw an error when the blocker was turned on. In traditional pages the error would happen without side effects. In an Angular 2 page it stops the change detection.

I have done my best to keep with the spirit of what the adsense provided code is supposed to do and how it is intended to behave. My goal is to bring their out-of-date requirements into a functional Angular 2 application. This currently works just fine in Angular 2's RC4 across all browsers.

Here's hoping they don't see it as TOS break...

To get Typescript to agree with all this you'll need to add a few lines to a .d.ts file:

```
declare interface Window {
  adsbygoogle: any[];
}

declare var adsbygoogle: any[];
```

These will make Typescript accept the `(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});` line in the ad component.

Comment: You'll have to add a definition to declare that it's there: `declare interface Window {
  adsbygoogle: any[];
}`

Comment: Where should I declare this interface?

Comment: In my typings folder I have a folder named after my project that contains a `custom.d.ts`. I put it in there.

Comment: I fixes the window.adsbygoogle compilation error but this still tries to assign a reference to a name that can't be found (`error TS2304: Cannot find name 'adsbygoogle'.`)

Comment: I just double checked my custom.d.ts, I have `adsbygoogle` declared twice. Once just like I said above in the Window interface, and a second time just as a var: `declare var adsbygoogle: any[];`

Comment: Now it compiles! It throws an exception that is getting consumed by the try-catch even with adblock disabled. I'll deploy and see how it behaves in production. Thanks!

Comment: How does it works with responsive ads? if there is no width nor weight, I see nothing

Comment: Hello. Can I ask who are still using this solution on 2023? Does it comply in Adsense policy?. Adsense is pretty strict lately. I want to use custom display ad.

Comment: It was working well for me up until about a week ago when reasons unrelated to this question resulted in me taking down my project. Nobody ever told me I was breaking TOS and my ads served successfully.

Answer (score 17):

This is working for me:

TopBannerComponent.ts ==>

```
    import {Component,OnInit,AfterViewInit} from '@angular/core'

    @Component({
      moduleId: module.id,
      selector: 'google-adsense',
      template: ` <div>
            <ins class="adsbygoogle"
                style="display:block"
                data-ad-client="ca-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
                data-ad-slot="8184819393"
                data-ad-format="auto"></ins>
             </div>   
                <br>            
      `,
   
    })

    export class TopBannerComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  
      constructor() {    
      } 
  
      ngAfterViewInit() {
         setTimeout(()=>{
          try{
            (window['adsbygoogle'] = window['adsbygoogle'] || []).push({});
          }catch(e){
            console.error("error");
          }
        },2000);
     }     
    }
```

Add this in your html where you want your ad to appear

```
<google-adsense></google-adsense>
```

Add google adsense script in your main html file

```
 <script async src=//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js></script>
```

Comment: This worked for me in Angular 4. Note: Remove the `setTimeout`, it's not necessary. Thank you Maayan!

Comment: thanks for this, I have 2 ads in the same component so I needed to call twice like this;      try{
       (window['adsbygoogle'] = window['adsbygoogle'] || []).push({});
       (window['adsbygoogle'] = window['adsbygoogle'] || []).push({});
     }

Comment: This worked for me in Angular 6. Thanks, ngAfterViewInit always saves some of my issues.

Comment: Works for me too in Angular 6.  Thanks!  (Also removed the setTimeout and works fine)

Comment: 'google-adsense' is the selector of the component. Did you add this component (above) to a module?

Comment: Hello. Can I ask who are still using this solution on 2023? Does it comply in Adsense policy?. Adsense is pretty strict lately. I want to use custom display ad.

Answer (score 5):

There is a module that works very well for me: [ng2-adsense](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-adsense).

If you'll choose to use it, your HTML code will look something like this:

```
<ng2-adsense
  [adClient]="'ca-pub-7640562161899788'"
  [adSlot]="7259870550">
</ng2-adsense>
```

After you install the module, you need to import it and add it to your NgModule:

```
import { AdsenseModule } from 'ng2-adsense';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AdsenseModule, // <--- Add to imports
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

And add this standard adsense code in your index.html:

```
<script async src=//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js></script>
```

Comment: Is it compliant with adsense policies?

Comment: @NaveedAhmed I think so. My website is live for about 2 months now and everything is good.. They didn't send any email or warning or something.

Comment: Just for the clarification are you using server side pre-rendering?

Comment: In my case it's not working. I follow the same steps

Comment: Can anyone help me out with this issue? I am running angular 7 SSR with ng2-AdSense. Been getting 400 errors for about a week now. Did anyone install with angular SSR?

Comment: In my case, it is not working. I am using it in an ionic project which is implemented using angular. It only shows blank space. It is not showing the ads.

Comment: As of now, I am able to show Auto ads on my angular SSR enabled website. However, still trying to figure out how to show native ads.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the above solutions I have created a simple solution that can be easy to implement.
This solution works with Angular Universal SSR (server side rendering)

In index.html add script provided from Adsense

```
  <script data-ad-client="ca-pub-xxxxxxxxx" async src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
```

In component.ts file,

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
 try {
   (window['adsbygoogle'] = window['adsbygoogle'] || []).push({});
   
   // If you have two ad on the page, then add this again.
   //(window['adsbygoogle'] = window['adsbygoogle'] || []).push({});


 } catch (e) {}
}
```

In .html file, place ad sense code whenever the ad needs to be displayed.

```
        <div  class="">
         <ins class="adsbygoogle"
            style="display:block"
            data-ad-client="ca-pub-xxxxxxxxx"
            data-ad-slot="zzzzzzzz"
            data-ad-format="auto"
            data-full-width-responsive="true"></ins>
        </div>
```

**Update:**
If ad doesn't show up then, set timeout in component.ts file

```
    ngAfterViewInit() {
     setTimeout(()=>{
      try {
       (window['adsbygoogle'] = window['adsbygoogle'] || []).push({});
      } catch (e) {}
     },500);
    }
```

Note:
Test your code on registered domain or subdomain. On localhost, the ad will not display.

Comment: Hello. Can I ask who are still using this solution on 2023? Does it comply in Adsense policy?. Adsense is pretty strict lately. I want to use custom display ad.

Comment: Not having any issue with adsense since this