# Using Google Adsense ads on Angular 2 application

Tags: angular, adsense

Is there any way to use Google Adsense ads on an Angular 2 app?

I have seen this [Google AdSense ads in Angular 2 components?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37580561/google-adsense-ads-in-angular-2-components) but the answer isn't actually working for me. I see a blank space instead of my ad. What I'm trying to place is responsive ad. I did exactly as the answer in the above question said, with this template code:

```
<div class="text-center">
    <ins class="adsbygoogle" style="display:inline-block;height:150px"
    data-ad-client="my ca-pub" data-ad-slot="my ad slot"></ins>
</div>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you manage to get your answer?

Answer (score 16):

The answer in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41629280/7334016) is worked for me. Even better I managed improve that code which can be use with dynamic Slot info.

banner.component.ts

```
import { Component, AfterViewInit, Input } from "@angular/core"
@Component({
moduleId: module.id,
selector: "google-adsense",
template: ` <div>
        <ins class="adsbygoogle"
           style="display:block;"
            data-ad-client="write_your_pub_"
    [attr.data-ad-slot]="data"
            data-ad-format="auto"></ins>
         </div>   
            <br>            
  `,

})

export class BannerComponent implements AfterViewInit {
@Input() data;
constructor() {}
ngAfterViewInit() {
setTimeout(() => {
 try {
    (window["adsbygoogle"] = window["adsbygoogle"] || []).push({});
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
  }
}, 2000);
} }
```

Add this in your html where you want your ad to appear

```
<google-adsense [data]="your_slot_id"></google-adsense>
```

Add google adsense script in your main html file

```
<script async src=//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js>/script>
```

Don't forget to add app.module.

In the other hand, Google adsense banners doesn't show in localserver and if it's in server it takes time to shown up. you can sure that it's working by changing backup ads property to

```
Fill space with a solid color
```

in Google Adsense portal.

Comment: Maybe things have changed since this post; Google AdSense ads do appear in locally-hosted sites.

Comment: does this still work ? (I come from the future, 2020 where angular 8 and 9 rule the world).

Comment: @bvdb it works in 2020. The most updated steps as of July,2020 https://stackoverflow.com/a/63045073/4067905

Comment: @Keyul unfortunately, that's angular SSR, (= server-side-rendering, which is a workaround, which basically turns an angular application in a static website. That works great for simple websites, but it's a nightmare for websites which use socket-io to stream real-time data).

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the best answer but I suggest using the module [ng2-adsense](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-adsense). From there you can smoothly place the ad via using the HTML tag `ng-adsense`.

Comment: has issues with ssr.

Comment: You need to handle the ssr case, why would you want to render ad unit on server? Just detect if you are in browser only then show ad unit. This plugin is easy to use and works well.

Comment: This module unfortunately does not support responsive ads on default..