# Google Ads solution for PWA/SPA?

Tags: single-page-application, progressive-web-apps, adsense, double-click-advertising

I've made a single page app via Angular, and plan to also make it a progressive web app in the next few days.

I recently realized that Google AdSense apparently doesn't like SPAs and my application has been denied twice. My app is a tool that allows users to create, manage, and share specific content, which I believe offers a ton of value.  When I was researching AdSense a while back, I definitely thought I would qualify as I didn't realize 'valuable content' specifically referred only to having a ton of words.

With that being said, it's 2019...is there no solution for serving Google ads on a web app that's not focused on articles, etc?? 
Google has tons of articles talking about how great PWAs are for users, yet it doesn't seem that they support ads for PWAs at all. I don't want to make a native mobile app, because I think a PWA that works on any device just makes more sense, so AdMob isn't an option. I've come across a few articles that indicate Doubleclick for Publishers (DFP) may be a solution, but when I try to login to that platform, it seems to be linked to my AdSense application and is either showing pending or access denied, depending on my current AdSense application status. I don't have another website that I could get approved first and then piggy back this app on that.

I'm also using firebase as my backed, which is why I'm pretty keen on advertising with Google as well. But obviously, if I have to go in a totally different direction to generate ad revenue with my app, I will.

Any insight into how I could make Google Ads work for my app or another good solution would be very much appreciated.

Comment: This is a huge problem I have been running into with my own PWA.  Why put so much weight behind the movement and not even support running ads on these apps?  So frustrating.

Comment: “I didn’t realize ‘valuable content’ specifically referred only to having a ton of words.” Absolutely right there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I came across the same problem, and my pwa got rejected due to having "little to no value". Adsense definitely looks to behind the times in this respect, but with growing popularity, I hope it will be addressed soon.

Have you looked into alternatives such as media.net?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion!  A quick look at the media.net website definitely looks promising.  I'm going to jump back on this project soon and will look into it more.

Answer (score 3):

I've run into the same problem I have a website that has little word content but takes in input and does finds solutions for scrabble, anagrams, etc. I have tried

AdSense
Media.Net
PropellerAds

None of them have taken my sit as of yet. There has to a company out there that I can use. I get a decent amount of traffic and I have no interest in adding a blog or whatever to a functional website since it would only clutter up the UI.

Comment: What I don't like about this solution is the kind of ads you can show. I'd like only some banners.

Answer (score 2):

Here we are in 2020 and I have AdSense ads working on our angular 8 sites. However, the solution goes away from a single page app. We had to setup Angular Universal to create HTML for the crawlers to see. Once that happened we got passed the ***'valuable content'*** problem as the crawler sees nothing on a SPA.  After getting an Angular Universal setup, look up how to get scripts into angular. That problem is solved here and the one we used to make ads happen:  [Google Adsense on Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39372270/using-google-adsense-ads-on-angular-2-application)

Comment: I also did Angular Universal to generate static HTML pages. However, I have a web-game, so not a lot of texts like a blog. What was your site, was it a blog?

Comment: Its stockbossup.com, so essentially a blogging site.  We had ads working in June but we have recently been hit by invalid traffic (eye roll)

Comment: @Chasterjohnson what do you mean by "invalid traffic"? did it create any problem to your adsense account? I am trying to use my main website adsense account to a pwa hosted on subdomain.

Comment: We got invalid traffic because we were getting direct users to our site, instead of referral traffic (or at least that's our theory, they don't tell you).  I removed all ads off our landing pages but it didn't matter.  We moved to media.net and we've had no problems.