# How to display ads using Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, asynchronous, ads

Ny website has been coded using Angular: www.sightmess.com 
I an trying to display ads on it. I have been approved by "TheMoneytizer" and after doing all I have to do, I couldn't display the ads on my website.

I know that  balise are quite difficult to display in Angular especially when there are some "document.write" or all of this kind of things in it. The main problem is that I am trying to display asynchronous ads using Angular... I tried to use postscribe but I couldn't display the ad ...

Moreover I tried to adapt the code which works for Google Adsense, but I couldn't do it ( the code is here: [Google AdSense ads in Angular 2 components?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37580561/google-adsense-ads-in-angular-2-components/41629280#41629280) )

I also tried to do this using iFrame, but i didn't work for this ad: [Javascript ads in Angular templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35140963/javascript-ads-in-angular-templates)

This is the script that I have to put on my website in order to display the ad I want:

```
<div id="39493-28"><script src="//ads.themoneytizer.com/s/gen.js?type=28"></script><script src="//ads.themoneytizer.com/s/requestform.js?siteId=39493&formatId=28"></script></div>
```

If anyone has an idea...

Thank you very much in advance!